# Get Manager field of Active Directory from SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, active-directory-import

Is there any option in ShaerPoint Designer 2013 workflow to access Active Directory "Manager" field?

So that we can get the manager of a user specified in particular field.

Comment: user profiles is your friend. If you have manager mapped from AD to your SharePoint online then there is no need to try going to Ad for the info...

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using SharePoint 2013 - got it.

If your workflow is a SharePoint 2010 workflow you can simply use the *Lookup Manager for User* activity.

If your workflow is a SharePoint 2013 workflow you will need to use the *Call HTTP Web Service* activity, with the following end point URL:

```
http://your-sharepoint-site/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=[%Workflow Context:Initiator%]
```

You can find full details [here](http://spmavericks.com/2014/10/30/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-find-manager-alternative/).

Comment: "Lookup Manager for User" activity? How random is that!

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a detailed instructions for getting the current user and the user's manager in SharePoint Online. I have also added a link for the JS and custom form for download. 
[Get Current Logged in User & Manager using REST API in SharePoint Online](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2016/10/get-current-logged-in-user-manager.html)

REST API Call:

```
 var url=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties"
```

Comment: Please include the relavent code pieces from your article that answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing about the forum rules. I have updated it.